# Can someone help me better understand zero or one in regex and possibly with nesting another within the same regex statement

Tags: python, regex, validation, irc

So I am creating a regex to recognize commands for a basic IRC and have come to one command that is giving me some trouble and has made me think about my previous commands a bit and possibly might allow me to correct some mistakes.

Essentially a JOIN message in this sense will allow a user to be added to a channel for chat with others, and for the purpose of this project a JOIN will also create the channel and add the user as its first member.  The user is already assumed to be logged in before this point so the only information needed is the channel or channels they intend to join.  This is where the problem comes where the RFC manual on IRC doesn't really have a hard limit so I think I will have to set some sort of soft limit of channels for them to join which.

JOIN #foobar                    ; Command to join channel #foobar.

JOIN #foo,#bar                  ; Command to join channels #foo and #bar.

These are two examples of possible basic commands.  Each must have no spaces, channels are delimited by a "," and a channel must begin with a special character being '&', '#', '+' or '!'.

I don't know if it would be something along the lines of the following would be what im looking for

"JOIN\s[(&|#|+|!)\w+][,(&|#|+|!)\w+]{0-4}"

The way I understand this setup if I did it correctly is there should be one channel followed 0 to 4 other, separated channels which I feel like would be easy to parse and work with due to the commas.  Can someone let me know if this is on the right track?

Also as an additional note, in previous commands I've tested for an exact correct command in terms of parameters but as long as there is a space is after the JOIN it should recognize it as a command but may just have incorrect parameters.  I would assume if the above regex was correct that something like this might be the correct way to deal with that.

"JOIN?[\s[(&|#|+|!)\w+][,(&|#|+|!)\w+]{0-4}]"

I could be way off but alot of these special symbols get fairly confusing.

Comment: Are you familiar with the website reg101.com?  It's a great side for testing regular expressions.   It's really hard to debug regular expressions just by looking at them.

Comment: @FrankYellin did you happen to mean regex101.com?

Comment: I did.  Bad typing.  Stackoverflow isn't letting me correct.  Does that site help you?

Comment: @FrankYellin it has helped a bit, I learned that I had to adjust the first part of my regex to JOIN\s(&|#|\+|!)\w+ but the additional optional channels separated by a , is still confusing me

Comment: I think you're also misunderstanding how to use []. You don't use | inside of [], unless you're actually planning on matching |.   [abc] means "a or b or c".  [^abc] means everything except abc.  [a-f] means a,b,c,d,e,f.  You need to be careful about ^ and - inside the [], but everything else is a character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like `JOIN\s[&#+!]\w+(,[&#+!]\w+){0,4}`

There were a couple of issues in your original.  `[]` don't quite do what you think they do, and the separator in `{}` syntax is a comma, not a hyphen.

Is there a reason you're limiting yourself to only five channels?

Comment: If you want the truth it is because I couldn't think of a way to dynamically create the channels for my server side interface and I felt although inefficient I just stuck with lists because as far as I can tell its the way most people seem to keep track of groups of users in programs such as these.

Comment: Also the original person who commented gave me a site where I could do some regex tests that were pretty useful and I had a friend give me some pointers, i did feel a bit dumb not realizing that the [ ] just was looking for a character in your list and didnt realize that ( ) could be used for more than the lists such as (&|#|\+|!).  And now that you point it out i think the [ &#\+!] might be a better more simple alternative.